# Is there some framework for testing GUI based on AWT?

Tags: java, user-interface, testing, awt

There is a lot of frameworks support testing Java GUI based on Swing but I can't find any open-source framework supporting AWT GUI testing. The framework should support script writing (not mere recording of user actions). Is there such framework or tool?

Answer (score 1):

You likely can use awt.Robot to write yourself such a tool.

Also meanwhile Swing and AWT can much better be mixed than in older times, you should consider to rewrite your UI, or at least do futur development Swing based.

Answer (score 1):

a good open source framework for Java GUI testing is [Maveryx](http://www.maveryx.com/).

It has many good point:

- It can handle Swing, AWT, Java Web Start (and soon) applets and SWT.
- There are no custom script language, you can write your test case in java.
- Thera are no GUI MAP dependences, you don't need any "capture and replay", only write your test and go!
- It's fully compatible with JUnit through the Maveryx Eclipse plug-in.

Mauro